# Javascript redirect to SSL causing 'partially encrypted' error

Tags: javascript, ssl, redirect

My website's login uses AJAX to post the credentials. It then checks for an 'error/success' to be returned and then acts accordingly.

This has worked fine up until I wanted to add SSL.

Original code:

```
if (output == 'success')
   window.location=window.location;
```

Replacement code:

```
if (output == 'success')
   window.location=String(window.location).replace('http://', 'https://');
```

That redirects the user to the SSL'd page but it causes Firefox to present a `content was partially encrypted` error.

How can I use Javascript to redirect to the SSL'd page without giving a warning?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine.

Usually the problem is that something (Javascript library, CSS file, image, etc) on an SSL page is not using SSL.

Use the Firebug "net" tab to examine everything loaded on the SSL page. Something is being referred to using http://

Comment: All GET requests on the SSL page show it pulling from HTTPS. No HTTP. If I manually refresh the page once it's loaded, it works fine.

Comment: Here's a similar problem: http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=12063.0

Try your pages in another browser. Is it FF specific?

Comment: Just tried it in Chrome and Internet Explorer. Chrome's URL bar lit up with no errors and IE lit up with the partially encrypted error. Firebug's net tab shows no HTTP content being loaded. The source of the page /does/ link to HTTP content (hyperlinks, no content being loaded) and the DOCTYPE and HTML XLMNS reference http:// but that shouldn't cause errors, right? :/

Comment: Hmmm. Unfortunately no good idea offhand. I suggest you try some stepwise refinement. Eg start with an empty SSL destination page and keep adding your SSL page's content until you get the error. I agree that the doctype shouldn't matter. But you could try changing it just to be sure. Try some other things too: empty the FF cache; load the JS script using ssl on the first page. I'm puzzled that the GET on the https page works ok when direct but not when it's a redirect. Maybe try Fiddler to really see what's being requested--more reliable than the Firebug net tab in some cases.